# Aptana Studio Eclipse IDE messes up color theme

Tags: eclipse, themes, aptana

Before I installed the Aptana Studio IDE for Eclipse my theme was set to "Dark" and the editors to "Sublime". 
After I installed Aptana all editors appeared in a white background color.
I know that Aptana has it's on settings for that but I want to separate the settings of Aptana and Eclipse. So Eclipse's settings should apply to all "normal" editors and the Aptana settings should only apply to its on editors. 
So right now, everything is white. And it only changes in black when I click "Apply to all (non-studio) editors" (In the Aptana settings).

But I don't want that!
I want to have my "normal" java editors like before and the Aptana editors should look different. But nothing will change if I set the settings in "preferences -> appearence -> color theme". Can anyone help me?